# Adding/Removing event on Different occasions

Tags: jquery

As a newbie in jQuery I stuck with a problem. The idea is as follows:
We have an admin panel, where you click on a BUTTON to add new member OR on a LINK to EDIT someone of the existing ones. Both clicks trigger one and the same window with difference that the LINK gives an ID, that gets data for the member and fill it in the form. Standard, isn't it? That was made from someone else and today I'm trying to override some functionality and add some new stuff. I got to this piece of code:

```
        // This happens to work.
        var handler_for_edit_window = function() {
            jQuery("#company_name_field").keyup(function(){
                jQuery("#company_name_feed").val(this.value.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase());
            });          
        };

        // I smelt the problem is somewhere here.
        jQuery( ".admin_buttons" ).bind( "click", handler_for_edit_window);
        jQuery( ".edit_row_btn" ).unbind( "click", handler_for_edit_window);
```

"handler_for_edit_window" works perfectly and does what it should do. However, the boss wanted to add functionality on the new members only and remove it on the existing ones. There for, I moved that functionality in "handler_for_edit_window" and trying to bind/unbind it depending on BUTTON/LINK. What infact happens is this:

1. Click on the BUTTON ( add new member) - have functionality
   1.1. Click on the LINK (edit existing) - have functionality
2. Click on LINK (edit) - no functionality
   2.1. Click on the BUTTON (new) - have functionality
   2.2. Click on the LINK (edit) - again have functionality

Decision - when we click the BUTTON it adding what is needed, but when we click the link we still have that and no way to remove it...

Will be happy if you give me some points and/or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to tag the `click` events so you can unset them seperately. jQuery allows you to do it like so:

```
$( ".admin_buttons" ).on('click.mytag', function() { } );
$( ".edit_row_btn" ).off('click.differenttag', function() { } );
```

Honestly, I didn't really understand your exact situation (your code is confusingly weird - why are you binding then immediatly unbinding. Also, you're unbinding with a function - what are you expecting that to do? run a function when it's *not* clicked? I have no idea...). But hopefully, you're getting the idea of event-tagging and how to use it

Two more things:

1. use `.on`, because `.bind` is an old syntax that has been deprecated for quite some time
2. you can use `$` instead of writing `jQuery` each time

Comment: The idea is to have one and the same window, that would appear on clicking either LINK or BUTTON...but with different behaviour - in first case  handler_for_edit_window = function() { }); should be triggered, in the second case - shouldn't. As appears, once handler_for_edit_window is invoked, it keeps it's state, no matter if the second click is on the LINK (where we should 'unbind' the function). I have tried with .on, .bind/.unbind, simple .click event..no luck. (Using 'jQuery' because not sure whether or not my new employer's source has some other js frameworks as well...preventing upfront)

Comment: @Musician There's no discernible difference between `bind`, `on` or `click` (the last one is just a shorthand for `.on('click'`) so there really wasn't any reason you would get different results. I have no idea what you mean by *"the idea is to have one and the same window"*. You need to understand I don't have the same frame of reference that you have, so I don't really understand what you're talking about. It will be beneficial if you edit your question and add some helpful details (a JSFiddle demo would be fantastic)